# If $A$ is symmetric positive definite then so is $2D-A$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I wish to show the followin: For any positive definite symmetric tridiagonal matrix $A$;
$$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}a_1 & c_1 & & & \\ c_1 & a_2 & c_2 & & \mathbf{0} \\ & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \\ \mathbf{0} & & c_{n-2} & a_{n-1} & c_{n-1} \\ & & & c_{n-1} & a_n\end{array}\right]$$
we have that $2D-A$ is positive definite as well. Here $D$ is the diagonal part of $A$.

This is coming from the context of the convergence of the Jacobi method. In particular, this is from an exam. The question gives

> [Hint: At the last step, you may find it useful to consider two vectors $x=\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\right)$ and $y=\left((-1) x_1,(-1)^2 x_2, \ldots,(-1)^n x_n\right)$.]

I really do not see how to use the hint. I have tried the following:

- I have calculated the other product of all possible combinations $x,x$ ; $x,y$, ... but nothing seemed to give above matrix.
- I have calculated $x^T A x$ and $y^T Ay$ to only get
  $$
  x^T A x +y^T Ay=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^2_k
  $$
  which doesn't seem to help at all.

**Question:** How do I show that $2D-A$ is positive definite using the aforementioned hint?

Comment: you did not define $D$

Comment: Apologies, $D$ is the diagonal of $A$

Comment: if you want to try using your hint, let $\Lambda$ be diagonal with $\lambda_i = -1$ if $i$ is odd and $\lambda_i = 1$ if $i$ is even.  Then $\Lambda A \Lambda^{-1}=\Lambda A \Lambda = 2D - A$ so they are orthogonaly similar matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said $D=\operatorname{diag}(A)$. Then $$2D-A$$ is the matrix flipping the signs of all sub diagonals, but the diagonal keep the same entries. Let $x$ be arbitrary vector and $y$ be the one in hints. Then by positive definiteness of $A$ we have$$y^TAy=\sum^n_{k=1}a_kx_k^2-\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}2c_ka_ka_{k+1}>0$$
Similarly, you can see
$$x^T(2D-A)x=\sum^n_{k=1}a_kx_k^2-\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}2c_ka_ka_{k+1}$$
So $2D-A$ is positive definite.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I just have a quick question. What was your intuition in doing this question? I am just not sure how I would have thought about this myself.

Comment: Since the matrix this question is relatively elegant, brutal force expanding $2D-A$, $v^TAv,v^T(2D-A)v$ may be give rise of some patterns already. Then you can see the difference between the two product above is just the sign of each $c_ka_ka_{k+1}$ changing from positive to negative. So you can imagine to consider some special vector (you want each term to reverse sign, so first mind maybe consider $-v$, but you see each entries will change twice sign, so maybe consider alternate signs $v$ {Of course, this time the special vector is already given in hints}). Hope these can help you.

Comment: That helped, thank you